# Select records in batches

Tags: sql, select, batch-file, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to get my data in batches, but not sure how to do it. To get it in halves, I was going to take the first half, order by in reverse order and then take first half again. I started off with this:

```
SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT * FROM Profiles
```

but I keep getting an error message saying that `'TOP Clause' support not available in SqlCE.`. I've read some posts that say that it is available but I just keep getting that error (my database is version 3.5). Is there another way to get data back in batches (in this case, halves, but I wouldn't mind a generic approach) using a query that works in SQLCE 3.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need data in batches?  If you're going to read all of the records anyway, splitting the work into 2 queries won't help anything.  In fact, it may cause more work on the database, as it'll require the records to be ordered - which may not be necessary otherwise.

Instead, open the Cursor / ResultSet / etc., and scroll through the records.  This will be the most efficient in terms of both the application and the database.